# My front-end app hosted on Heroku is having requests to a proxy api URL overwritten

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app client and an api that retrieves database content hosted at different URLs on Heroku. Inside my client's package.json the proxy for api calls is `"https://theclients-api.herokuapp.com"` (this isn't the actual URL). However, when this api is called, the request is instead sent to `https://theclients-front.herokuapp.com/getcontent` (the root URL of the front-end client) instead. Why is this happening, and what could I do to fix it?

Comment: Keep in mind that proxy only has effect in development (with npm start). Ref: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: Ah, so I'll probably need to go in and manually set the api endpoint for each request?

Comment: Is it production? Why not use a env file and set the URL in it and use the env variable.